# Docker container stop running automatically a second after starting

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-container

When I try to run my mysql container, it's starting and automatically stops after 1 or 2 seconds. I never had that problem before. Here are the logs of the container :

```
180124  8:14:18 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180124  8:14:18 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
180124  8:14:18 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.59) starting as process 1 ...
180124  8:14:18 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
180124  8:14:18 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180124  8:14:18 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180124  8:14:18 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180124  8:14:18 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180124  8:14:18 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
180124  8:14:18 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180124  8:14:18 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180124  8:14:18 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180124  8:14:18 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
180124  8:14:18  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180124  8:14:19 InnoDB: 5.5.59 started; log sequence number 32263726
180124  8:14:19 [ERROR] Aborting

180124  8:14:19  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
180124  8:14:20  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 32263726
180124  8:14:20 [Note]
```

Before that problem, I installed a new package into my container with apt-get and had some problems with the my.cnf file but I don't think that's the reason of my current issue (maybe I am wrong).

This container contains data that I don't want to lose. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try to recreate the container from the scratch? If you have the `/var/lib/mysql` data persisted, then the container is just a throw away data. Anyway this question does not belong to the StackOverflow.